# mysqld: Can't create/write to file (Errcode: 13)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I installed mariadb on my archlinux box recently and wanted to run mysqld with different data and tmp directories

```
[mysqld]
user        = mysql
port        = 3306
datadir     = <datapath>
tmpdir      = <datapath>/tmp
```

When running mysqld I get the following error messages:

```
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '<datapath>/tmp/ib8dOkCX' (Errcode: 13)
InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13 
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '<datapath>/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13)
[ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '<datapath>/aria_log_control'
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting

[Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I have made sure that the mysql user is the owner and has the proper permissions on the data and tmp directories.

When running mysqld as root, everything works just fine. When using the default tmpdir I still get the error when create/write to file /aria_log_control. Anyone who knows where I fail?

Answer (score 1):

you should replace `<datapath>` with real path to data files which contains folder tmp